# Is it possible to change languages in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have VS 2008 Professional, with English set as the current language. Is it possible to change the current language to German, Russian or other languages, and, if so, how please?

Thanks, and take care,
ragims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

```
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> International Settings
```